# MATLAB genetic algorithm constraint (all variables can't be zero at the same time in a binary environment)

Tags: matlab, optimization, genetic-algorithm

I'm using MATLAB `ga` function for my optimization problem. In my problem, I have some decision variables which are integer (0 and 1: I specified lower bound, upper bound, and `IntCon` for it) plus two continues varibales. Otherwise, all integer variables can't be zero at same time, so at least, we need a single "one" variable among integers. How can I implement mentioned constraint in MATLAB?

Comment: Are you sure (MATLAB version of) `ga` can be used for integer-only optimization problems (Combinatorial Optimization)? I know it can be used for mixed-integer though.

Comment: @NKN. Yes. There is an option for it in `ga` function winch I'm currently use it: `IntCon`.

Comment: `IntCon` is used to define integer constraints, it is not clear to me how are you using it to solve an only integer problem though.

Comment: As you said, I'm using it to define my integer variables but I'm not able to define mentioned constraint in my problem.

Comment: `ga can solve problems when certain variables are integer-valued.` Not all the variables but certain variables. Can you share more info about your problem.

Comment: @NKN that's true. I simplified my question. I have two other variables that are continues which I ignored those. I revised the question. thanks.

Comment: Whit `IntCon` you specify which variable is integer, for instance `IntCon=[2 4]` means that your second and forth variables are integer. So it cannot be `0`. I think you can add a constraint such as `sum([x(2) x(4)]>0` to prevent all zero solutions.

Comment: @NKN. Can you prepare a sample code for this constraint and add your answer? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a Mixed-Integer optimization problem and it can be solved using `ga` in MATLAB. As mentioned in the documentations: `ga can solve problems when certain variables are integer-valued.` Not all the variables but certain variables. So you should have at least one real variable among the other integers.

Whit `IntCon` options, you can specify which variables are integer, for instance `IntCon=[1 3]` means that your first and third variables are integer. To avoid both integer variables to be `0` at the same time, I think you can add some inequality constraints.

For instance look at the following example:

Let's say we want to find the optimum value for the Ackley function with `5` variables (e.g. in 5 dimensions), `[x(1)...x(5)]` and let's assume that the first and third variables, `x(1)` and `x(3)`, are integers. We can write the following script:

```
nVar = 5;               
lb = -5*ones(1,nVar);   % define the upper bound
ub = 5*ones(1,nVar);    % define the lower bound
rng(1,'twister')        % for reproducibility
opts = optimoptions('ga','MaxStallGenerations',50,'FunctionTolerance',1e-3,'MaxGenerations',300);
[x,~,~] = ga(@ackleyfcn,nVar,[],[],[],[],lb,ub,[],[1 3],opts);
disp('solution:');disp(x)
```

On my machine, I get this solution:

```
solution:
                   0  -0.000000278963321                   0   0.979067345808285  -0.000000280775000
```

It can be seen that `x(1)` and `x(3)` are integers and both `0`. Now let's say as you mentioned, they both cannot be `0` at the same time and if one is `0` the other should be `1`. Here the boundaries of the Ackley's problem allows the variables to be in the range defined by lower and upper bounds. However, in your case the lower and upper bounds should be defined as `[0]` and `[1]` for both integer variables.

Now I want to avoid both variables to be `0`, so I can write the following linear inequality constraint:

```
% x(1) + x(3) >= 1  
% x(1) >= 0 
% x(3) > 0
```

These inequalities should be written in form `Ax <= b`:

```
A = [-1 0 -1 0 0
    -1 0 0 0 0
    0 0 -1 0 0];
b = [-1
    0
    0];
```

Now if we run the optimization problem again we see the effect of the constraints on the output:

```
[x,~,~] = ga(@ackleyfcn,nVar,A,b,[],[],lb,ub,[],[1 3],opts);
disp('solution');disp(x)


solution
   1.000000000000000  -0.000005031565831                   0  -0.000011740569861   0.000008060759466
```

Comment: Why `x(1) >= 0` constraint has equal sign and the other doesn't have? Did you mention this sign in your MATLAB code?

Comment: MATLAB considers the inequalities in the form `Ax <= b`.